# How to regenerate grub after dual booting?

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, kali-linux

I had dual boot, Windows 10 and kali linux latest 2017. Now I replaced windows 10 with windows 8.1 . And now there is no grub option. Windows 8.1 loads directly. Is there any way to solve this problem ? Or should i reinstall kali again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll most likely have to reinstall Kali. Windows doesn't play nice when installing it on a system that already has another OS installed first. Normally when setting up a dual-boot system, you always want to install Windows first and then install Linux second.

From [PCWorld:](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2955460/operating-systems/dual-booting-linux-with-windows-what-you-need-to-know.html)

> When you install Windows after Linux, Windows ignores Linux, doesn’t
>   know how to resize its partitions, and overwrites the Linux boot
>   loader with its own.

Since you weren't starting from scratch here you didn't have the option of installing Windows first since this is a reinstall of Windows on a system that already had a preexisting Linux partition. In a case like that you can try repairing Grub first if you really want to attempt to salvage your Kali partition. If it's there's nothing worth salvaging, just reinstall Kali.

There's some chance Windows only overwrote Grub with its own bootloader and didn't erase your Kali partition, so you can attempt to simply repair Grub and hope everything else was left intact. One method of doing this is to boot into a live Linux USB/CD and repair Grub as described here at [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows):

> 1. Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a
>      LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.
> 2. Install and run Boot-Repair.
> 3. Click "Recommended Repair".
> 4. Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose
>      between Ubuntu *(in your case, Kali) and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

General approach to fix a grub bootloader. Warning, this can wreck your windows bootloader or make everything unbootable if something goes awry!

- Mount the linux system managing that bootloader from a rescue disk (eg a live linux CD)
- chroot into that mountpoint
- mount /sys and /proc
- if it is an older (menu.cfg style) grub, you might have to tweak /etc/mtab and delete device.map. WARNING: Do not try to revert grub to an old version (even if it is less confusing to configure) unless you are sure that older version can deal with your linux root filesystem (for example, 0.xx versions mostly won't work with ext3 if the inode size has not been set to 128 at formatting time).
- if the linux system is udev-driven, create a fallback set of device files running "MAKEDEV generic" in /dev
- rerun grub-install, with the correct whole disk device (eg /dev/sda) as a target (this should send whatever MBR was installed by another OS straight to hell)
- leave chroot and mountpoint (you will need to umount /sys and /proc to do that)
- try to boot. If the linux system starts to boot but aborts or kernel panics, you will need to check and correct the grub parameters temporarily from the grub command line. Hint: You can use a device name instead of these pesky uuids for the kernel root= parameter; to set the grub root, you will need the grub specific syntax (eg msdos(0,1) ).
- upon successfull boot, rerun grub-install again
- set up whatever is needed to chainload your other operating systems